# I'm new and i want anyone help sum using vuejs

Tags: vue.js

so i'm new using vuejs and i need to make a sum of 2 inputs and 1 select
it's a tip calculator, in a restaurant, people will pay like 20$ for their food and they need do a tip on the final payment, if the service quality was good, tip will be 20% of the total value.
the first input it's the price, the select it's the tip %, the second input its to you pay alone or share with someone.

**Example:**
Food: 100$
Service: excelent (tip 30%)
Amount of people paying: 2
So 100 + 30% / 2 = 130$ total, 65$ each person

I tried a lot of things, but none was working, i just need to learn how to sum, can someone help me?

```js
    export default {
      methods: {
        soma: function() {
          this.items.push({
            valor1: "",
            valor2: "",
            valor3: "",
          })
        };
      },
    }
```

```html
    <template>
      <main>
        <h1>Calculadora de Gorjetas</h1>
        <li v-for="item in items"><label>Valor da Conta?</label>
        <input type="number" v-model="item.valor1" />
        <label>Como foi o Serviço?</label>
        <select v-model="item.valor2">
          <option value="5">5% (Péssimo)</option>
          <option value="10">10% (Ruim)</option>
          <option value="15">15% (Ok)</option>
          <option value="20">20% (Bom)</option>
          <option value="25">25% (Mais que Bom)</option>
          <option value="30">30% (Perfeito)</option>
        </select>
        <label>Quantas pessoas irão dividir?</label>
        <input type="number" v-model="item.valor3" />
        <h4 id="resultado">Valor da conta: R$ para cada pessoa</h4>
        </li>
      </main>
    </template>
```

Comment: Post what you have tried, where you got stuck and any errors you might receive.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't sum anything. Give it a try and we'll help you debug. Also install the [Vue Devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) in your browser they help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your data to the html elements and then trigger the calculation for example through a button click.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="number" v-model="price" />
    <input type="number" v-model="numberOfPersons" />
    <select v-model="selectedTipPercentage">
      <option value="5">5% (Péssimo)</option>
      <option value="10">10% (Ruim)</option>
      <option value="15">15% (Ok)</option>
      <option value="20">20% (Bom)</option>
      <option value="25">25% (Mais que Bom)</option>
      <option value="30">30% (Perfeito)</option>
    </select>
    <button @click="calculate()">Calculate</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      numberOfPersons: 0,
      price: 0,
      selectedTipPercentage: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    calculate() {
      const priceWithTip =
        (this.price / 100) * this.selectedTipPercentage + this.price;
      console.log(priceWithTip / this.numberOfPersons);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of vue.js is to bind data to your attributes.

This can be done by using the `v-model` directive on your elements.

Then, to calculate sums, you can use a computed property to calculate the sum of the items and the tip.

You can then divide this result by the number of user to get the sum by user

---

Here is a small working example

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    apples: 1,
    APPLE_PRICE: 100,
    tip: 0,
    numberOfUser: 1,
  }),
  
  computed: {
    itemsSum(){
      return this.apples * this.APPLE_PRICE * (1 + this.tip / 100)
    },
    
    itemsSumPerPerson(){
      return this.itemsSum / this.numberOfUser
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <input v-model="apples" type="number">
  <label>apple ({{APPLE_PRICE}})</label>
  
  <br />
  
  <input v-model="tip" type="number">
  <label>tip (in %)</label>
  
  <br />
  
  
  <label>Number of user :</label>
  <input type="number" v-model="numberOfUser"/>
  
  
  <h2> Sum : {{itemsSum}}</h2>
  <h2> Sum per person : {{itemsSumPerPerson}}</h2>
</div>
```